# How to close a jquery UI dialog with iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is how I initialize the dialog:

```
$('a.dialog').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" src="/controller/action" frameBorder="0"></iframe>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Title',
        zIndex: 1,
        show: 'fast',
        hide: 'slow',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        position: 'middle'
    }).width(600);
});
```

How can I close it from inside the iframe?

For example, I'd like to have a link inside the iframe that will close the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.parent` or `window.top` to reference parent window. Starting from there, you should be able to find your dialog with jquery and close it. Something like

```
$(window.top.document).find('#externalSite').dialog('close');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent

Comment: Or `window.top.$.find('#externalSite').dialog('close');` to use the jQuery object on the parent window directly, in case the page in the frame doesn't need/want jQuery itself.

Comment: That doesn't work. But this does: $(window.top.document).find('.ui-widget-overlay, .ui-dialog').remove();

Comment: @Richard I'm not familiar with jui api, looks like it's called 'destroy': http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-destroy

Comment: @Richard I assumed that you know how to do it without iframes already.

Comment: @Richard Maybe it doesn't find iframe because you didn't insert it in the document? Try `alert($(window.top.document).find('#externalSite').length)`.